Error: read ECONNRESET while connecting to my postgres db on render.com
Error while connecting to my Postgres database
this is a setup for a next.js project using typescript
// src/utils.ts
import { Client } from "pg";

export async function getClient() {
  const client = new Client({
    user: "...",
    password: "...",
    database: "...",
    port: 5432,
    host: "hostname.singapore-postgres.render.com",
    ssl: true,
  });
  await client.connect();
  return client;
}


// src/create-table.ts

import { getClient } from "./utils";

async function createTable() {

    const createUserTableQuery = `
        ...
    `;

    const client = await getClient();

    await client.query(createUserTableQuery);
    const createTodosQuery = `
       ...
    `;
    await client.query(createTodosQuery);
    console.log("Table created successfully!");
}
createTable();


the error am getting:
node dist/create-table.js
node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
errno: -4077,
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read'
}
I did some research, may be the problem is from the side of render.com.

Here's some background you can read about the error: How do I debug error ECONNRESET in Node.js?
Can you add some line numbers to your code so we can see which line number is generating the error? Your block of text indicating lines 289 and 217 need more context. For example, is the error caused when calling your getClient() method, or when you call one of your client.query() methods, and if so which one?
A few things you can try:
If the connection fails immediately when trying to connect, try adding this to the end of your connection string: ?sslmode=no-verify
If the connection is failing after your app is running for a while, it could be an idle timeout from the server which hasn't received any data from your app in a long while, and should be addressed in your code to reconnect and retry.
